# Append New Row to Kusto Table

Tags: kql, azure-data-explorer, kusto-explorer

I want to manually add a new row to kusto table called "StudentTable". I was wondering what's the syntax? Assuming the table already exists and has column names of `StudentID` and `StudentName`

The documentation doesn't have any instruction: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-ingestion/ingest-from-query

Would this be the syntax?
`.append async StudentTable <| StudentID = "12345", StudentName = "John Doe"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're missing the `print` operator.

`.append StudentTable <| print StudentID = "12345", StudentName = "John Doe"`

another options is to use the [`.ingest inline` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-ingestion/ingest-inline).

e.g.: `.ingest inline into table StudentTable <|12345,John Doe`

**NOTE** that ingesting single records using either of the options above isn't recommended for frequent operations in Production environments.

- you can use [streaming ingestion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingest-data-streaming?tabs=azure-portal%2Ccsharp) for scenarios in which data 'trickles' infrequently and in small volumes.